# Android/Kotlin - Usando argumento do tipo Parcelable para o meu Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, kotlin

Estou tentando passar um objeto para dentro de um Fragment e não consigo selecionar o tipo da classe no argumento do Fragment de destino pois o botão "OK" fica desabilidato.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A classe **Estoque**:

```
package app.controledeestoque.model

data class Estoque (
    val id: String,
    val descricao: String,
    val foto: String,
    val preco: Double,
    val unidade_medida: Int,
    val quantidade_disponivel: Int
)
```

Se eu configurar o `app:argType` no `mobile_navigation.xml` manualmente, ocorre erro na execução do app.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_editar_estoque"
    android:name="app.controledeestoque.ui.estoque.EditarEstoqueFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_estoque"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_editar_estoque">
    <argument
        android:name="estoque"
        app:argType="app.controledeestoque.model.Estoque" />
</fragment>
```

Segue o erro:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in app.controledeestoque:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in app.controledeestoque:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in app.controledeestoque:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating app.controledeestoque:navigation/mobile_navigation line 27
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: app.controledeestoque.model.Estoque is not Serializable or Parcelable.
```

Alguém sabe o motivo de eu não conseguir usar minha classe Estoque no argumento do Fragment?

Tentei usar as soluções propostas aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664447/how-to-pass-object-of-type-parcelable-to-a-fragment-using-navigation-type-safear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa que sua classe *Estoque* implemente o `Parcelable`.

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Estoque (
    val id: String,
    val descricao: String,
    val foto: String,
    val preco: Double,
    val unidade_medida: Int,
    val quantidade_disponivel: Int
) : Parcelable
```

### Explicação

O que uma classe que implementa a interface Parcelable faz é escrever todos os seus dados (ou somente os que o desenvolvedor achar necessário) em um objeto Parcel que é a entidade que será transmitida (para outra Activity, Fragment, para buffer de utilização do SavedInstanceState, ...), a leitura desses dados que estão no objeto Parcel também é uma das funcionalidades da classe que implementa o Parcelable. Fonte: [Parcelable no Android](https://www.thiengo.com.br/parcelable-no-android-entendendo-e-utilizando).

Você pode saber mais em: [Gerador de implemetação parcelable](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Na mensagem de erro explica o porque o erro está acontecendo se você ler o log e olhar a última linha.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: app.controledeestoque.model.Estoque is not Serializable or Parcelable.
```

Nesse caso você precisa converter seu objeto em Serializable ou Parcelable.

Exemplo de como a classe ficaria:

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Estoque (
   val id: String,
   val descricao: String,
   val foto: String,
   val preco: Double,
   val unidade_medida: Int,
   val quantidade_disponivel: Int
): Parcelable
```